# SQL sort list but put specific element first in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I want to sort my image list using date or upvotes received. There is also the possibility to use the link of an opened image something like`www.mywebsite.com/images?selected=73723.jpg` to open up an image directly while the other sorting terms still apply.

The selected image should be the first element but after that it should again be sorted by date or upvotes as it would normally. Here is what I have:

```
$sortingstring = "image_uploads.UPVOTES DESC"; // <-- order by upvote
$sortingstring = "image_uploads.THMPATH = '".$selectedCode."'"; // <-- selected image

$query = "SELECT * FROM test_users, image_uploads ORDER BY " . $sortingstring;
```

In this example we can see the code for upvote sorting and for filtering out the selected image. How can I combine both sorting by upvotes and display the selected image first, it doesn't seem to work no matter what I tried?

Comment: You'll need either two separate queries or maybe a Union query

Comment: if I could make it all in one go it would save me a lot of time.. if you want to help you could give me the solution to this using union.. but thanks for the hint!

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can do it with the FIELD function, something like this

```
ORDER BY FIELD(image_uploads.THMPATH, "your code") DESC, image_uploads.UPVOTES DESC
```

Here is a simple example

```
CREATE TABLE `items` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sort_field` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

ALTER TABLE `items` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

INSERT INTO `items` (`id`, `sort_field`) VALUES
(1, 1),
(2, 3),
(3, 2);
```

Query

```
SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY FIELD(items.id, 1) DESC, sort_field DESC
```

Result

```
| id | sort_field |
|----|------------|
|  1 |          1 |
|  2 |          3 |
|  3 |          2 |
```

Comment: thanks, just a quick question, what's the "your code" parameter, what code are you talking about.. is it not like this somehow: `SELECT * FROM test_users, image_uploads ORDER BY FIELD(image_uploads.THMPATH, "???"), image_uploads.UPVOTES DESC`

Comment: Ah I see it's probably `SELECT * FROM test_users, image_uploads ORDER BY FIELD(image_uploads.THMPATH, $selectedCode), image_uploads.UPVOTES DESC`

Comment: @Miger it is your $selectedCode variable

Comment: it doesn't seem to work `image_uploads.UPVOTES DESC` seems to overwrite the statement inside the `FIELD()`, I cannot get it to work..

Comment: @Miger try FIELD(image_uploads.THMPATH, $selectedCode) DESC, ...